# How to change border color of NSScrollView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I could customise border type through `-[NSScrollView setBorderType:]`, but what about border color?

Answer (score 2):

**1**

Import `QuartzCore framework` to your App.

**2**

Then import that in `.h` file on which class where you want to set the border. like:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

**3**

Try this for setup of your border, I hope it help you:

```
myScrollView.layer.cornerRadius=10.0f;
self.myScrollView.wantsLayer = TRUE;

myScrollView.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
myScrollView.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor redColor]CGColor];//change according to your requirement.
myScrollView.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But unfortunately it does not work for me.

Comment: The answer is right. You need to set myScrollView.wantsLayer to true. (Or do it in Interface Builder)

Comment: I finally managed to make it work with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045005/change-border-corlor-of-nstableview

Comment: Actually when I tried Suraj's answer, I can see border radius is different(although not in a right way), but the color is not changed.

Comment: No. I don't know. I know your answer is supposed to work on any `NSView`.

Comment: May be I didn't do it right. I put a test app on [github](https://github.com/beretboat/ScrollViewBorder) with this answer. Could you point out what's wrong and push a fix? @SurajSukale

Answer (score 0):

To make https://github.com/beretboat/ScrollViewBorder work, you'd have to "Embed In" the scroll in a view. Than set the borders on that view. The NSScrollView is not your typical NSView.